# Move data from Google Cloud-SQL to Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataflow, gae-quotas

I am trying to move my data from Cloud SQL to Cloud Datastore.

There are a bit under 5 million entries in the SQL database.

It seems like I can only move over 100,000 entities per day before I get a quota error.

I can't figure out which exact quota I'm exceeding, however I have exponential backoff to make sure I'm not sending it too fast.

Eventually it hits 5 minutes and the connection to the SQL server dies, but I don't think the writes per second quota is the problem. And I don't see any other quota exceeding in my APIs page or the App Engine API page.

I have tried two different APIs to write the records.

The GCP Datastore API

import googledatastore
Here is the code:
https://gist.github.com/nburn42/d8b488da1d2dc53df63f4c4a32b95def

And the Dataflow API
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import WriteToDatastore
Here is the code:
https://gist.github.com/nburn42/2c2a06e383aa6b04f84ed31548f1cb09

Here is the error I see after one or two hundred thousand good writes.
RPCError: datastore call commit [while running 'Write To Datastore/Write Mutation to Datastore'] failed: Error code: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED. Message: Quota exceeded.

I'm running this on compute engine.

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked for a quota increase and someone at google checked my account to find the problem.

Here is their reply.

> I understand that you want to know what specific quota you are
>   reaching whenever you try to backup your Cloud SQL to Cloud Datastore.
>
> Upon checking your project, it seems that the problem is that your App
>   Engine application is at or near its spending limit. As of this time
>   of writing, the Datastore Write Operations you have executed costed
>   you 1.10$, which will be refreshed after 5 hours. It can definitely
>   cause your resources to become unavailable until the daily spending
>   limit is replenished. Kindly try to increase your spending limit as
>   soon as possible to avoid service interruption and then run or execute
>   your datastore write operations.
>
> Give this a shot and let me know what happens. I will be looking
>   forward to your reply.

This fixed the problem. I just needed to go into app engine and set a much higher daily spending limit.

Hopefully the code I included above will help others.